# How to deploy from an artifact registry to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, cicd, build-automation, google-artifact-registry

I have this app that has its builds uploaded to an artifact registry, and I wish to deploy the latest artifact to Firebase Hosting automatically, via CD script.

But... Firebase doesn't seem to support hosting artifacts directly from a registry, like this. All the documentation and tutorials I've found are about building and deploying the app from the pipeline (i.e. having the files in a folder inside the build container).

I managed to work around this by actually downloading the artifact inside the pipeline, extracting it, initializing *firebase-tools* and then deploying. Sketchy.

Is it possible to configure a pipeline to directly upload (deploy) an artifact to Firebase hosting?

---

extra details that I'm not sure if are important:

- I'm uploading the build (no source) to an NPM registry
- which is Google Artifact Registry
- and using Google Cloud Build for the CD pipeline
- the app is a React frontend
- yeah

Comment: "*I managed to work around this by actually downloading the artifact inside the pipeline, extracting it, initializing firebase-tools and then deploying. Sketchy.*"  That's not sketchy - that's pretty normal. You'd have the same process if you were deploying to any other web hosting platform, or were using any other CD product in tandem with your artifact registry.

Comment: Modern web platforms like Vercel opt to make this process easier by bypassing the concept of an artifact registry altogether, and instead monitor your GitHub for commits. When you commit, the CD runs, pulls the source, builds it, and deploys it all automatically. There is no "artifact" since the idea is that you can recreate and redeploy it any time relatively quickly by using the named commit.

Comment: I know this trend... but I had problems with this in the past. Not sure if it was a bug on the compiler itself, or maybe a dependency that changed (I know, shouldn't be possible, the fact is that my later build had incorporated a bug that was not there in the first time, despite having a `package-lock.json`). I'm hoping to avoid re-building when I need to rollback. Besides, it seems more coherent not needing to build more than once (for apps that take long to build). -- and that's why I'm specifically trying to deploy from a registry, instead of just building and deploying as usual